# Building Bowtie index failure (tophat2, bowtie2)

Tags: bioinformatics

**(Note: tags should be tophat2 and bowtie2 but I do not have the points to create new tags)**

Greetings: I am using Tophat2 (command line) to analyze RNA-seq data and I am encountering some errors.

**Here is the call:**

```
tophat2 -o tophat2_results/ -G ref_data/BA000007.2.gtf --transcriptome-index=transcriptome_data/RNA_LBG01b_241_filteredQ indices/BA000007.2 data_files/RNA_LBG01b_241_filteredQ.fastq
```

**Here is the error:**

```
[2015-12-29 12:58:33] Checking for Bowtie
          Bowtie version:     2.2.4.0
[2015-12-29 12:58:33] Checking for Bowtie index files (genome)..
[2015-12-29 12:58:33] Checking for reference FASTA file
[2015-12-29 12:58:33] Generating SAM header for indices/BA000007.2
[2015-12-29 12:58:33] Reading known junctions from GTF file
    Warning: TopHat did not find any junctions in GTF file
[2015-12-29 12:58:33] Preparing reads
     left reads: min. length=12, max. length=342, 202732 kept reads (1315 discarded)
Warning: short reads (<20bp) will make TopHat quite slow and take large amount of memory because they are likely to be mapped in too many places
[2015-12-29 12:58:39] Building transcriptome data files transcriptome_data/RNA_LBG01b_241_filteredQ
[2015-12-29 12:58:40] Building Bowtie index from RNA_LBG01b_241_filteredQ.fa
    [FAILED]
Error: Couldn't build bowtie index with err = 1
```

**Version Information:**
TopHat v2.1.0        Bowtie2 version 2.2.4              Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)

**System Information:**
CentOS Release 6.7

**How I got here and what have I tried:**

I am using E. coli (Accession: BA000007.2) for my reference genome which can be found here: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/BA000007.2

I obtained my GTF file from Ensemble (ftp://ftp.ensemblgenomes.org/pub/release-29/bacteria//gtf/bacteria_9_collection/escherichia_coli_o157_h7_str_sakai/)

I made my indices using bowtie2-build (before tophat2 call)

```
bowtie2-build -f ref_data/BA000007.2.fasta indices/BA000007.2
```

I am aware that the error I am receiving is affiliated with different names appearing in the first column in the *.gtf file and the name of the reference fasta file. If I understand this correctly, every entry in the 1st column should be BA000007.2 where most of the names in the 1st column where "Chromosome". To fix this, I did the following:

```
awk '{FS=OFS="\t"}{print "BA000007.2", $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9}' pathToGTF/BA000007.2_ensemble.gtf > pathToGTF/BA000007.2.gtf
```

*#Please note the commented build information (e.g., #!genome-build ASM80120v1) at the beginning of ensemble gtf file would create undesirable output from the awk command has been addressed*

I also changed the termination of the fasta file from *.fasta to *.fa

Questions:

1. Did I properly put the kibosh on any problems arising from differences in naming between the 1st column of the gtf file and the name of the fasta file (BA000007.2, BA000007.2.fa)?
2. When I peruse output in the logs directory, there are several errors (g2f.err & similar errors in ftf_juncs.log) with lines beginning with:

   Warning: invalid start coordinate at line: 
   BA000007.2    ena    gene    -194    2502    .    +    .    gene_id "BAA31757"; gene_version "1"; gene_name "tagA"; gene_source "ena"; gene_biotype "protein_coding";

There are indeed negative numbers in the gtf files, but not in the genbank file (quick search in vim). Could this be the source of the error? I commented out the specific lines and deleted them from the file -- both approaches still result in the error.

3. Is there anything readily seen that could be causing the "*Couldn't build bowtie index with err = 1" error*?

I have been stuck on this for a couple of days so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would [biostars](https://www.biostars.org) be a better place for this question

Comment: If nobody knows the answer, you'll need to compile Bowtie2 sources yourself.

Comment: @Ismail M, Great suggestion, however, my question is already on biostars (101 views, no answers (yet)).

Comment: @Student T -- please expand. Since I have already built the index files with bowtie2-build and have all the initial files for running the tophat command, what other sources are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the source of the problem. It was the header in the referential fasta file. The initial header was:

```
>gi|47118301|dbj|BA000007.2| Escherichia coli O157:H7 str. Sakai DNA, complete genome
```

Where is should have been

```
>BA000007
```

So...if the fasta file is called abc123.fa, then the header in the fasta file must be >abc123. The first column in the gtf file must also be abc123.

Please note that I changed the base from BA000007.2 to BA000007 in all of my calls, and I renamed all files without the .2 in the name. It may still work with the .2, but I did not test it out ("*The basename is the name of any of the index files up to but not including the first period.*" [tophat manual]) (Thank you AM). Lastly, I renamed in fasta files from *.fasta to *.fa.